# JMeter JSON Path Extractor - need select only certain Id

Tags: json, path, jmeter

I am getting JSON with several Id records. I need only the parent level Id what is highlighted at the picture below. JSON Path is: .Id, see below[image]:
[image]

Currently I am getting back all Id:

```
LoanHistoryIDs_1=54bb6a6ecbda714f6c1c4348
LoanHistoryIDs_2=5570675ecbda712418a92f4c
LoanHistoryIDs_3=53fed26acbda7151983a9d18
LoanHistoryIDs_4=54bb6a6ccbda714f6c1c4344
LoanHistoryIDs_5=54bb6a6ecbda714f6c1c4349
LoanHistoryIDs_6=54bb6a6dcbda714f6cffd23f
LoanHistoryIDs_7=53fed26acbda7151983a9d18
LoanHistoryIDs_8=54bb6a6ccbda714f6c1c4344
```

How can I filter only what I need?

part of JSON from comment:

> [{ "Id": "54bb6a6ecbda714f6c1c4348", "Lenders": [{ "Id": "5570675ecbda712418a92f4c", "Name": "MORGAN STANLEY MORTGAGE CAPITAL HOLDINGS LLC" }], "Borrowers": [{ "Id": "53fed26acbda7151983a9d18", "Name": "120" }], "TransactionDate": null, "Type": "Original Loan", "Date": "2013-12-16T00:00:00Z", "Amount": 135, "MaturityDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z", "Structure": "CMBS", "CMBSList": [{ "Id": "54bb6a6ccbda714f6c1c4344", "Name": "Morgan Stanley Bank of America Merrill Lynch Trust 2014-C14" }] }, { "Id": "54bb6a6ecbda714f6c1c4349",

Comment: [{
 "Id": "54bb6a6ecbda714f6c1c4348",
 "Lenders": [{
  "Id": "5570675ecbda712418a92f4c",
  "Name": "MORGAN STANLEY MORTGAGE CAPITAL HOLDINGS LLC"
 }],
 "Borrowers": [{
  "Id": "53fed26acbda7151983a9d18",
  "Name": "120"
 }],
 "TransactionDate": null,
 "Type": "Original Loan",
 "Date": "2013-12-16T00:00:00Z",
 "Amount": 135,
 "MaturityDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z",
 "Structure": "CMBS",
 "CMBSList": [{
  "Id": "54bb6a6ccbda714f6c1c4344",
  "Name": "Morgan Stanley Bank of America Merrill Lynch Trust 2014-C14"
 }]
},
{
 "Id": "54bb6a6ecbda714f6c1c4349",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need plugin, use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)  with `$.Id` as JSON Path Expressions value to get the id value under root, not including other id in hierarchy

**EDIT**

In case of JSON array use or `[0].Id` for first Id or `[*].Id` for all Ids.

Comment: I am getting the same 8 results, but I need 2 only. It looks the mechanism JSON Extractor or JSON path are identical.

Comment: Please add to question **text** of valid JSON you get in response

Comment: Added to my post, as here it doesn't allow >500 char

Comment: You can Edit your own question with JSON, from the part of the JSON I think you need to use `[0].Id` as JSON expression

Comment: This worked: [*].Id with [0].Id I was getting only the first one.Thanks a lot for your help and quick response.